# Ancient greek variant not working in polyglossia package

Tags: xetex, errors, languages, polyglossia

I'm using the polyglossia package to set ancient greek as secondary language.
The code works fine when I just type

```
\setotherlanguages{greek}
```

However an error appears when i change it to

```
\setotherlanguages[variant=ancient]{greek}
```

Here is the error: (that appears both on my PC and on Overleaf):

```
! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'polyglossia/[/hyphenmins' requires a value.
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass [11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}


\usepackage{fontspec}                           % Customizzazione dei font
\setmainfont[                                   % Computer Modern
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  BoldFont=cmunbx,
  ItalicFont=cmunti,
  BoldItalicFont=cmunbi,
]{cmunrm}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}                  % Times New Roman
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}                    % Font sans-serif
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}               % Font monospazio
\usepackage{polyglossia}                        % Linguaggi multipli
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}                    % Lingua principale: italiano
\setotherlanguages[variant=ancient]{greek}      % Lingua secondaria: greco antico

\begin{document}

Testo di esempio:
Θουκυδίδης Ἀθηναῖος ξυνέγραψε τὸν πόλεμον τῶν Πελοποννησίων καὶ Ἀθηναίων

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: you have an `s` too much, the command is `\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}`

Comment: You are right...thank you very much